# How to use NSURL:setResourceValues() in Swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, swift

All the examples of using setResourceValues() are like this:

```
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
try? path?.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```

However this doesn't compile with Swift 4.1, the error is

> Cannot convert value of type 'URLResourceValues' to expected argument
>   type '[URLResourceKey : Any]'

How do I convert a URLResourceValues to a [URLResourcesKey:Any] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a method of `URL` on an instance of `NSURL`.

`NSURL` defines:

```
func setResourceValues(_ keyedValues: [URLResourceKey : Any]) throws
```

while `URL` defines:

```
func setResourceValues(_ values: URLResourceValues) throws
```

Since you are using Swift, do not use `NSURL`. Update your code so `path` is of type `URL` instead of `NSURL` and your call to `setResourceValues` will work.